# How do I pass a class type to a method call using Spring Expression Language in an XML bean configuration?

Tags: xml, spring, spring-el

I want to inject a bean using XML configuration. The constructor takes an object of type `OrderService` which I get from calling the factory method `serviceBroker.getService()`. That method takes a class type as argument. How do I specify that class type in the method call using `Spring Expression Language`? Here is what I have right now and it is giving an error when deploying:

```
  <bean id="extendItemRequestProcessor" class="com.site.ExtendItemRequestProcessor">
    <constructor-arg type="com.site.service.order.OrderService" value="#{serviceBroker.getService(com.site.service.order.OrderService.class)}"/>
  </bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the T operator.

```
 T(com.foo.MyClass)
```